# Why wont my jsp page recognize my angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, scope, controller

jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head><title>Sample JSP Page</title></head>

<body>

<div  data-ng-contoler="mainController" >
 <input type="text" data-ng-model="greeting">
This is from angular {{greeting}}
</div>

<button data-ng-click="test()">doSomething</button>


</body>




<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/toast.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/mainController.js"></script>
<script src="app/services.js"></script>

</html>
```

My module myApp

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($logProvider){
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

My mainController.js

```
 myApp.controller('mainController',function($scope, $http, myAppFactory) {
 $scope.greeting = null;
 $scope.greeting = "Jo jo jo it worked!!!!";


 $scope.test = function test(){
    var v= "asddas";
    myAppFactory.test().success(function(date){
        var a = data;
    })

 }

 });
```

My service.js   myAppFactory

```
myApp.factory('myAppFactory', function($http) {

var factory = {};

factory.test = function(){
     return "test";
}

return factory;
});
```

When i press the doSomething button it should go to scope.test
The problem is that the controller is not available.
When i start eclipse, and go to the page on chrome, press f12
i can find the contoller with my code in it, but it never runs.

On start the "greeting" is set to be:
 $scope.greeting = null;
 $scope.greeting = "Jo jo jo it worked!!!!";

But on the page it is blank, on f12 i see with breakpoints that the code
never worked.

The input field with the data-ng-model="greeting"
is working fine. When i go to the page and write something in it
it is instantly displayed on change.

All files are loaded on the debug window. app, mainController and service.
On load the pages gets all files with status 200 OK

But i cant enter with breakpoints in the mainController.

Comment: I moved the closing div tag to the bottom to catch the doSomething button.

Comment: in your jsp page you have misspelled controller, you have contoler instead of controller

Comment: Ty man, i feel so embarrassed right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change typing mistake

```
<div  data-ng-contoler="mainController" >
```

to

```
<div  data-ng-controller="mainController" >
```

Hope it will work.